# How to select not null datas using whereHas in LARAVEL

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-8, laravel-7, laravel-query-builder

Let me make it simple, In my models, I have **countries** and **cities**. My goal is, I want to select and display only the **cities** that has **shops** and it should also have **`datas`** and the employees should not be `NULL`

In the below given array, my **city** has two **shops** where `id - 13` that doesn't have any datas and `id - 19` which is having data.

```
[
    {
    "id": 1,
    "created_at": "2022-06-02T06:07:31.000000Z",
    "updated_at": "2022-06-02T06:07:31.000000Z",
    "name": "Niue",
    "cities": [
                {
                "id": 13,
                "created_at": "2022-06-02T06:07:44.000000Z",
                "updated_at": "2022-06-02T06:07:44.000000Z",
                "country_id": 1,
                "name": "North Michealbury",
                "shops": [] //empty
                },

                {
                "id": 19,
                "created_at": "2022-06-02T06:07:44.000000Z",
                "updated_at": "2022-06-02T06:07:44.000000Z",
                "country_id": 1,
                "name": "Millsmouth",
                "shops": [
                            {
                              "id": 1,
                              "created_at": "2022-06-02T06:14:37.000000Z",
                              "updated_at": "2022-06-02T06:14:37.000000Z",
                              "city_id": 19,
                              "name": "Roberts-Okuneva",
                              "employees_count": 146
                            }
                        ]
                }
            ]
    }
]
```

This is the code that, I have written in my controller. The goal is, I want to select and show only those cities that has shops with employees.

```
   return Country::with(['cities','cities.shops'=>function($employee){
        $employee->withCount('employees')->where('city_id',19);
    }])->whereHas('cities',function($city){
        $city->where('cities.id',19);
    })->get();
```

These are my models, each of them has a `hasMany` relationship

**Country model**

```
 public function Cities(){
        return $this->hasMany(City::class);
    }
```

**City model**

```
public function shops(){
    return $this->hasMany(Shop::class);
}
```

**Shop model**

```
   public function employees(){
        return $this->belongsToMany(User::class,'shop_employees','shop_id','employee_id');
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try

```php
//Get all cities which have shops having at least one employee
return Country::with([
    'cities',
    'cities.shops' => function($query) {
        $query->withCount('employees');
    }
])
->whereHas('cities', function($query) {
    $query->whereHas('shops', function($query) {
        $query->has('employees');
    });
})
->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

i found another solution querying with clause.

```
 return Country::whereHas('cities',function($cities){
        $cities->where('country_id',1);
    })->with(['cities'=>function($shops){
        $shops->has('shops')->where('cities.country_id',1);
    },'cities.shops'=>function($employee){
        $employee->withCount('employees');
    }])->get();
```